# Create Visualforce Page with dependent multi-select picklist

Tags: visualforce, controller, custom-controller

I am new to Salesforce and trying to make a new VF page. I have three custom objects:

1. Students (list of students)
2. Course Details (course time, start date, room, etc.)
3. Student Course Detail Junction Object - so i can have a many to many relationship

I want to create a VF page where I can choose student and assign multiple course details to that one student, all on the same page.

I've found a custom controller that basically is a [multiselect controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html).

I want a picklist on the top of the page that has the Student names as options.

What do I need to do to have both controllers on one page? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The heading seems incorrect, you are trying to include 2 multi select picklist on a single page. Controller refers to a class which controls the logic/processing of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Through the junction object, once a student is selected, you should have access to all of the available courses related to the student. You're talking about two separate picklists. The first is a single picklist where you select a student.

The second sounds like a multiselect where you'd select the courses you wanted for that student. That said, you might want to break that up to where you could select one course at a time to add to a list. Each course might be offered at more than one different time, thus you might have what's called a dependent picklist where once you selected a course, you'd then select the time it's offered. The entire block of picklists would all need to be nested inside of an `<apex:form>` tag.

I highly recommend you look at the following resources: I recommend the following resources [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/), the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm) and [Visualforce in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf). Also, don't forget to visit [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) and try out the VisualForce module you'll find there as well as an additional learning resource.